# I want to make a service API call during iOS app install and uninstall

Tags: ios

Is it possible to make an API call in the following cases:

1. when app installing
2. once app is installed, but not opened the app at least once
3. when app uninstalling

Any thoughts on these please let me know.

Comment: No such thing, sorry.

Comment: No, You can't..

Comment: API call is a part of iOS Application, How can you detect and call API on App installation and all other as you want.